# How to identify DataFrame columns containing specific pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I want to identify all the columns that contains only a specific pattern, which is 32 characters long hex code. So if I have the following DataFrame for example

```
Incident                                SLA Contributor                         Priority       Last Group
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000329edb523708f8079044db9619f0        DAP/IBM                                    P2        3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425
3bb02e66db97a70cf8079044db961907        EUX/SD                                     P4        102a3748dbee2200d4c17868bf9619b1
3bb02e66db97a70cf8079044db961907        fa863d3fdb1d3740205a328c7c961982           P4        102a3748dbee2200d4c17868bf9619b1
82cf9812dbd80098b6629c4adb96198d        DAP/IBM                                    P4        3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425
9e12a6c11b228c14de583150cd4bcbbb        3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425           P4        64f4d44fdbf666004f9a7cbdae961919
b17c3f43db9bf700b6629c4adb9619ca        NET/BT                                     P3        64f4d44fdbf666004f9a7cbdae961919
fa863d3fdb1d3740205a328c7c961982        DAP/IBM                                    P2        3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425
```

So it should identify the `Incident` and `Last Group` column, because all the values in these two columns are 32 characters long hex code. Some values of `SLA Contributor` column are 32 long hex code but there are other values also which does not follow that pattern, so it should not include `SLA Contributor` column.

I am not sure if I have to loop through all the values of a column to check, or there is any better solution for it. I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks, Sattyaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more general solution first select only strings columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html).

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for test length per columns and then test if all values are `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last filter columns names:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(object)

mask = df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.len().eq(32)).all()
```

If need test hexadecimal 32 length string use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `na` parameter with `True`:

```
mask = df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$", na=True).all()
```

---

```
cols = df1.columns[mask].tolist()
print (cols)
['Incident', 'Last Group']
```

List comprehension alternative is:

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if df[c].str.contains(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$", na=True).all()]
print (cols)
['Incident', 'Last Group']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `all` and a regular expression:

```py
hex_regex = re.compile(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$")  # regular expression of an hex code of 32 digits

hex_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].map(lambda x: hex_regex.match(x) is not None).all()]  # check that all the entries in a column match the required format
```

If nan are allowed, you should skip them, so use the following:

```py
hex_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[df[col].notnull()][col].map(lambda x: hex_regex.match(x) is not None).all()]
```

In both cases, `hex_cols` is `['Incident', 'Last Group']`.

Here a full example (with nan values):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['0000329edb523708f8079044db9619f0', 'DAP/IBM', 'P2', '3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425'],
        ['3bb02e66db97a70cf8079044db961907', 'EUX/SD', 'P4', '102a3748dbee2200d4c17868bf9619b1'],
        ['3bb02e66db97a70cf8079044db961907', 'fa863d3fdb1d3740205a328c7c961982', 'P4', '102a3748dbee2200d4c17868bf9619b1'],
        ['82cf9812dbd80098b6629c4adb96198d', 'DAP/IBM', 'P4', '3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425'],
        ['9e12a6c11b228c14de583150cd4bcbbb', '3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425', 'P4', '64f4d44fdbf666004f9a7cbdae961919'],
        ['b17c3f43db9bf700b6629c4adb9619ca', 'NET/BT', 'P3', '64f4d44fdbf666004f9a7cbdae961919'],
        ['fa863d3fdb1d3740205a328c7c961982', 'DAP/IBM', 'P2', '3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425'],
        [None, 'DAP/IBM', 'P2', '3a03ba3a6f22f2c44484f5269f3ee425'],
        ['b17c3f43db9bf700b6629c4adb9619ce', 'DAP/IBM', 'P2', None],
        [None, 'DAP/IBM', 'P2', None],
    ],
    columns=['Incident', 'SLA Contributor', 'Priority', 'Last Group'],
)

hex_regex = re.compile(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$")

hex_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[df[col].notnull()][col].map(lambda x: hex_regex.match(x) is not None).all()]
```

If you like one-liner, you can compress the previous code:

```py
[col for col in df.columns if df[df[col].notnull()][col].map(lambda x: re.compile(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$").match(x) is not None).all()]
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm! I wish I could accept this one also as correct.